# How to sum overlapping values in a time range dynamically in R?

Tags: r, time, overlap

I have a dataset comprised of project titles, start date, end date, and a value point assigned to each project that describes how intensive it is. I want to visualize this data dynamically (f.ex. with plotly) and display the sum of the value points that overlap in a given time range. Here is some sample data:

| Project Title | Start date | End date | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project A | 20/04/2019 | 14/07/2023 | 10 |
| Project B | 18/06/2020 | 15/05/2022 | 5 |
| Project C | 01/12/2021 | 19/04/2023 | 3 |
| Project D | 09/07/2023 | 17/08/2024 | 2 |

(many many more rows)

In the example above, Projects A, B, C overlap, having a total of 20 points, and later projects A and D overlap for a short while, having a total of 12 points for a few days.
I have melted the dataframe to long format to make a Gantt chart, ex:

```
df_tidy <- dataset2 %>% 
  melt(dataset2, 
           id.vars = "Project Title", "Points"),  
           measure.vars = c("start_date", "finish_date"), 
        variable.name = "variable")
```

I need now to find a way to sum the Points that overlap in time, and somehow plot it in the Gantt chart. The goal is to be able to see the amount of total Points at any given time for project planning. My main thought was to have it displayed with plotly when hovering over any given time, but I can't find a way to do it. Does someone have an input on how to do it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not plotly, but you get the idea. In particular, I create a new data frame with an observation for each point in time where the point count changes. This can then be plotted with `geom_step()`.

```r
# Data
d <- structure(list(name = c("Project A", "Project B", "Project C", 
"Project D"), start = structure(c(18006, 18431, 18962, 19547), class = "Date"), 
    end = structure(c(19552, 19127, 19466, 19952), class = "Date"), 
    pts = c(10, 5, 3, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Generate interval variable
d <- d |> 
  mutate(interval = start %--% end) 
  
# New data set with point values where changes occur
points <- 
  tibble(dates = c(d$start, d$end + days(1))) |> 
  arrange(dates) |> 
  mutate(pts = map_dbl(dates, \(x) d$pts[x %within% d$interval] |> sum()))

pts_range <- range(points$pts)

# Calculate positions for combining discrete and continuous scale of names and points in plot
d <- d |> 
  mutate(pos = name |> 
           factor() |> 
           as.numeric() |> 
           {\(x) (x - 1) / (max(x)-1) * (pts_range[2] - pts_range[1] - 1) + pts_range[1] + 1}()
         )
```

```r
ggplot(d) +
  geom_linerange(aes(xmin = start, 
                     xmax = end,
                     y = pos, 
                     color = name), 
                 size = 12) +
  geom_text(aes(x = start + ((end - start) / 2),
                y = pos, 
                label = name)) +
  geom_step(data = points, 
            aes(x = dates, y = pts), 
            alpha = .6,
            size = 2) + 
  labs(x = NULL, 
       y = "Points") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi shs! Thank you very much for the reply - worked like a charm! I had a bit of trouble understanding this chunk though: d <- d |> 
  mutate(pos = name |> 
           factor() |> 
           as.numeric() |> 
           {\(x) (x - 1) / (max(x)-1) * (pts_range[2] - pts_range[1] - 1) + pts_range[1] + 1}()
         )
Could you kindly dumb down the logic of the last line? Much appreciated!

Comment: Since the `name` variable is categorical, but we want to put it on the same axis as the points, we need to assign a numeric value to each name. So I turn it into a factor from which I take the underlying numeric vector. But these are integers. Thus, rescale them to the same range as the `pts` variable with padding of 1 on each side